# disable zoom on amchart map

Tags: zooming, amcharts

Im using AmChart for Maps, When I double click on any part of map it zoom, I want to disable this zoom.

I have tried setting properties like

```
"dragMap": false,
"autoZoom": false,
 map.zoomControl = {
        zoomControlEnabled: false,
        panControlEnabled: false
    };
```

This works in IE, but still in Chrome it Zoom on double click.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`zoomOnDoubleClick`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#zoomOnDoubleClick) to false in the top level of your chart config to disable zoom on double click:

```
map = AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "zoomOnDoubleClick": false,
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c70ebbe49930ae2ff2403c1e340cc02b?editors=0010)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks